# Best phrasing vertically

Tags: meaning

I am practicing Chinese style painting and I would like to integrate Chinese lettering into my art, the goal being to make complete traditional pieces with a poem vertically written included.
My first written words I think should be “chun zhen mei”. I am putting it next to a bamboo branch and a single leaf. The idea I want to get across is natural/simple/ unadulterated beauty.

1. Is “chun zhen mei” (is Zheng or zhen more appropriate?) the right wording?
2. In which order should I right these vertically?
   Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want.

Transpose left to right writing to vertical writing by leftmost is top, rightmost is bottom.

春天真美 chūntiān zhēn měi （If that's what you want to say.)
Spring is truly beautiful

Here is a spring poem from 杜甫 Dù Fǔ （712 - 770）

《春夜喜雨》
《Rain on a Spring Night》
【唐】杜甫
【Tang】Dù Fǔ

好雨知时节，当春乃发生。
Good rain knows season, only happens in spring.
随风潜入夜，润物细无声。
Wind-borne it steals in by night, silently spreading a  thin film of moisture.
野径云俱黑，江船火独明。
On the wild way the clouds are all black, only the river boat fire is bright.
晓看红湿处，花重锦官城。
At dawn I see red and wet patches, and drooping flowers in Jǐnguān.

Happy painting!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the words you seek are "純(chún)- pure/simple", "真(zhēn)- real/true", "美(měi) - beauty".

You can leave the word order as is, "純真美", or reorder it as "真純美".

Note that there is already a similar, yet very popular, phrase out there - "真善美"; 善(shàn) - good, virtuous, charitable.

Comment: Quote:- "The idea I want to get across is natural/simple/ unadulterated beauty", i.e. "...a bamboo branch and a single leaf".  That being the intention, I think you are right that "純真美" is the correct phrase OP had in mind.